# jquery: select options and background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Greetings,
Having a such select box:

```
<select id="events">
    <option value="1" style="background-color:green;">Event 1</option>
    <option value="2" style="background-color:yellow;">Event 2</option>
    <option value="3" style="background-color:blue;">Event 3</option>
    <option value="4" style="background-color:red;">Event 4</option>
</select>
```

At the **initial** browser render of this selectbox and **each time a selection is done**, I want the selectbox "events" to get the background-color of the selected option.

How can this be achieved via jquery or via regular javascript ?

Comment: Can $("form option") be used instead of an ID? Or some method so ALL of your select menus are styled the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Alert color on initial page load
var bkg = $("#events option:selected").css("background-color");
    alert(bkg);

//Handle change event and alert color when selection is done
$(function(){
 $("#events").change(function() {
    var bkg = $("#events option:selected").css("background-color");
    alert(bkg);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

```
$('#events').bind('change', function() {

   var bgc = $(this).find('option:selected').css('background-color');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$("#events").change(function() {
    $(this).css("backgroundColor",
      $(this).find(":selected").css("backgroundColor")
    );
}).change();
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/8x5wD/).  **But**, this won't work in all browsers, especially in IE the `<select>` element is notoriously unstyleable (for lack of a better...or real word).  It'll work in the browsers that support it and just have no effect in the ones that don't.  You may instead wait to style a parent element to give an indicator in all browsers, [something like this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/8x5wD/1/).

Comment: Your first code doesn't work in firefox. Instead, I'd recommend taking  the `style` attribute completely like so - http://jsfiddle.net/qEPPC/2/

Answer (score 0):

IE friendly way, this has to applied to `option` tag.

```
$(this).html($(this).html());
```